# get value from dynamic key in clojure map

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I have a clojure map

```
+  69 (def names {:production "prayag"                                                                     
+  70             :staging    "upd"})
```

I need to get a value from a key variable `environment` that would be dynamic.

Something like below throws Exception,

```
+  72 (defn get-name [environment]                                                                                   
+  73   (let [ 
+  74        name (:(environment) names)]                                                                 
+  75        println name                                                                           
+  76     ))
```

Stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid token: :
    at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:219)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.interpretToken(LispReader.java:326)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:211)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1157)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$ListReader.invoke(LispReader.java:982)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1148)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$VectorReader.invoke(LispReader.java:1083)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1148)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$ListReader.invoke(LispReader.java:982)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1148)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$ListReader.invoke(LispReader.java:982)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:185)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7060)
    ... 55 more
```

While following code,

```
+  72 (defn get-name [env]                                                                                    
+  73   (let [                                                                               
+  74        name (keyword(":" env) names)]                                                                                                   
+  75        println name                                                                           
+  76     ))
```

**gives**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
    at nepleaks_engine.util.utility$fn__3885.invoke(utility.clj:74)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3458)
    ... 58 more
```

**And**

```
+  72 (defn get-name [env]                                                                                    
+  73   (let [                                                                              
+  74        name (.get names env)]                                                               
+  75        println name                                                                           
+  76     ))
```

gives

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at nepleaks_engine.util.utility$util.invoke(utility.clj:81)
    at nepleaks_engine.core$_main.invoke(core.clj:14)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:411)
    at user$eval5$fn__7.invoke(form-init336568295343421746.clj:1)
    at user$eval5.invoke(form-init336568295343421746.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6609)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7020)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:294)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:299)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:327)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:362)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:440)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```

Comment: Where and how is `environment` defined? Assuming it's something like `(def envinroment :production)` then you can do `(let [name (environment names)])`. Keep in mind that it would throw an exception if names is not a function or a symbol. You could also do `(names environment)` which might return nil instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`(:(environment) names)` is not a valid form. Unless `environment` is a function of no arguments, you will get an error from wrapping it in parens. usage of `:` to create keywords is done at read time, before `(environment)` is evaluated, so you do not see the previous error, and the reader attempts to resolve `:` on its own, which is not a valid input to the reader.

`(keyword(":" env) names)` attempts to call the string ":" as if it were a function. It is not one. Also the spacing leads me to beleive that you expect `keyword(arg)` to work as it would in an Algol family language. It will not. The proper usage is `(keyword arg)`.

here is what works, with a few equivalent syntaxes avaliable for convenience (they all do the same thing):

```
user> (def names {:production "prayag" :staging    "upd"})
#'user/names
user> (def environment "staging")
#'user/environment
user> (names (keyword environment))
"upd"
user> ((keyword environment) names)
"upd"
user> (get names (keyword environment))
"upd"
```